# IR-Keytable support for the variable frequency & modulation

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-buster, uv4l, v4l2

I am working on the RPI-CM4 with the ir-keytable library.

I am using the TSMP97000 sensor to read the modulated data from the IR transmitter(Remote).

it-keytable library is working successfully with the TSOP1738 receiver. (Which has a fixed frequency of 38KHz).
TSMP97000 has a variable frequency range & also supports different modulation types.

Will ir-keytable supports reading the modulated data?

Comment: why don't you determine the answer experimentally?

Comment: the TSMP97000 does not contain a demodulator ... it is only a sensor

Comment: @jsotola: I have made some test cases with both TSOP1738 & TSMP97000. ir-keytable library works successfully with the TSOP sensor. 
Will you please help me to know What should I do to the Make ir-keytable library compatible with TSMP97000? 
OR 
Is there any other solution for remote learning using TSMP97000?

Comment: The TSOP is module, not just a sensor ... you could probably use a microcontroller, such as an arduino to demodulate the IR signal from the TSMP and feed the result to the Raspberry Pi

Comment: @jsotola: Will you please help me to know, Is there any reference library or SDK that has the capability to communicate with TSMP (i.e modulate & demodulate the IR signals)